# check if Gutenberg is currently in use

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

How can I check if the editor that is currently being used is Gutenberg in a WordPress plugin?

I need this because Gutenberg lacks `post_submitbox_misc_actions`, so I need a fallback which will only be used if the current editor is Gutenberg.

Comment: Do you mean like is_gutenberg_page() with function_exists (untested)?

Answer (score 15):

### Necessary API Functions/Methods:

You'll need [`WP_Screen::is_block_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_screen/is_block_editor/) method to check if you are currently in the Gutenberg Editor (Since WordPress 5.0).

Also, if you install Gutenberg as a separate plugin, then you'll have the `is_gutenberg_page()` function available to do the same check.

So for an overall solution, you'll need to combine these two.

Of course, this has to be checked from the admin panel pages and when the internal data is ready to call the function. So **you'll have to do the check using a suitable hook**. For example, *if you check this using **`init`** hook, it **will not work***.

Gutenberg itself checks the `is_gutenberg_page()` function from `gutenberg_init()` function, which is loaded using `replace_editor` hook. So `replace_editor` hook is a good place to do this check.

However, I'd suggest the use of `admin_enqueue_scripts` for making the check, since:

1. `admin_enqueue_scripts` is the first hook that is fired after the same `is_gutenberg_page()` check Gutenberg makes itself.
2. Because of the nature of Gutenberg, you're more likely to load external scripts / styles for your purpose.
3. `admin_enqueue_scripts` is a well known hook and it's only fired from admin panel pages. So front end is not affected by it.

> Having said that, **if all you need is to enqueue some scripts/styles**, then you may use [`enqueue_block_editor_assets`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/) hook for editor assets and [`enqueue_block_assets`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_assets/) hook for both the editor and frontend assets (since WordPress 5.0).
>
> I'm not providing the related CODE here as it wasn't directly asked in the question, but it may be enough for most purposes.

### Solution:

> Sample CODE for Gutenberg check

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_gutenberg_editor_action' );
function wpse_is_gutenberg_editor() {
    if( function_exists( 'is_gutenberg_page' ) && is_gutenberg_page() ) { 
        return true;
    }   
    
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( method_exists( $current_screen, 'is_block_editor' ) && $current_screen->is_block_editor() ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function wpse_gutenberg_editor_action() {
    if( wpse_is_gutenberg_editor() ) { 
        // your gutenberg editor related CODE here
    }   
    else {
        // this is not gutenberg.
        // this may not even be an editor, you need to check the screen if you need to check for another editor.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only working with the Gutenberg plugin, it doesn't work in wp5 if plugin is not installed

Comment: `is_block_editor` is required for wp5.0 +

Comment: UPDATE: should now work for WP 5.0+ & if Gutenberg is installed as a Plugin.

Answer (score 11):

The function `is_gutenberg_page` is from the Gutenberg plugin, while the `is_block_editor` method is available from 5.0. This function below combines both into a single checking function.

The code below is from [Freemius SDK](https://github.com/Freemius/wordpress-sdk/commit/8a87d389c647b4588bfe96fc7d420d62a48cbac5), props to their team:

```
function is_gutenberg_page() {
    if ( function_exists( 'is_gutenberg_page' ) &&
            is_gutenberg_page()
    ) {
        // The Gutenberg plugin is on.
        return true;
    }
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( method_exists( $current_screen, 'is_block_editor' ) &&
            $current_screen->is_block_editor()
    ) {
        // Gutenberg page on 5+.
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer moving forward.

Answer (score 5):

1. Gutenberg has been integrated in WordPress 5.0 and now you can check by using `use_block_editor_for_post` function.

   ```
   if(use_block_editor_for_post($post)){
     //Block editor is active for this post.
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, when creating new post you can use `use_block_editor_for_post_type` function to check if gutenberg is active for this post type.

   ```
   if(use_block_editor_for_post_type($postType)){
   //Gutenberg is active.
   }
   ```

Comment: My variation was https://pastebin.com/Fv3gYdhp

Answer (score 2):

`has_blocks` is the way to go to check content, but also note if you are just checking if the block editor screen is being used in the admin area, you can do a check like this (to account for both the new block editor and Gutenberg plugin):

```
if (is_admin()) {
    global $current_screen;
    if (!isset($current_screen)) {$current_screen = get_current_screen();}
    if ( ( method_exists($current_screen, 'is_block_editor') && $current_screen->is_block_editor() )
      || ( function_exists('is_gutenberg_page')) && is_gutenberg_page() ) ) {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, but I don't think you need to call `global $current_screen`.

Comment: true, I tend to code examples this way as I don't know what context they will be in - they could break easily depending on that... I just added an additional is_admin and isset check for this purpose.

Comment: In the current WP version (5.0.2) the above snippet does not work when it is executed in a function attached to the `current_screen` hook because `is_block_editor` is set later than that. It only works if it is executed at a later time (i.e. `load-(page)`). This seems a bug in WP.

Answer (score 2):

The `WP_Screen Object` now contains a boolean property for this. The following is working for me:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'get_current_screen' ) ) {
  return false;
}

$screen = get_current_screen();
$is_block_editor = $screen->is_block_editor;
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_screen/is_block_editor/

Answer (score 1):

[Gutenberg 3.6](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/08/17/whats-new-in-gutenberg-17th-august) introduced functions like `has_blocks` and `has_block`. They replace the deprecated `gutenberg_post_has_blocks` function.

If `has_blocks` returns true than Gutenberg was used while editing the post.

You can either use `has_blocks()` without params if the `$post` global is already set(for something like a query loop) or check the post content directly with `has_blocks( $content )`

Answer (score 1):

Here I have shared the custom function which you can use to check Gutenberg is enable or not.

```
if ( is_gutenberg_enable() ) {
    // Do your code
}
```

This is a custom function:

```
/**
 * Check if Gutenberg is enable.
 * Must be used not earlier than plugins_loaded action fired.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_gutenberg_enable() {

    $gutenberg    = false;
    $block_editor = false;

    if ( has_filter( 'replace_editor', 'gutenberg_init' ) ) {
        // Gutenberg is installed and activated.
        $gutenberg = true;
    }

    if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.0-beta', '>' ) ) {
        // Block editor.
        $block_editor = true;
    }

    if ( ! $gutenberg && ! $block_editor ) {
        return false;
    }

    include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';

    if ( ! is_plugin_active( 'classic-editor/classic-editor.php' ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    $use_block_editor = ( get_option( 'classic-editor-replace' ) === 'no-replace' );

    return $use_block_editor;
}
```

Comment: This is [one of the forks](https://gist.github.com/mihdan/8ba1a70d8598460421177c7d31202908) of [the kagg-design script](https://gist.github.com/kagg-design/18883cb7ab310e818ef91ffa81088d47)? Is including wp-admin's plugin.php really a good idea?

Comment: It is a little bit different. As per standard, we need to avoid the plugin.php but in some cases, you can use it if you want. Here I have used for the plugin check.

Comment: @Rup you can just do `if ( ! class_exists( 'Classic_Editor' ) ) {` instead of including plugin.php.

Answer (score 0):

In WP 5.0 and higher, a function 'has_blocks' is present in /wp-includes/blocks.php, so you can use:

```
    if ( function_exists('has_blocks')) {
        $this->isGutenberg = true;
    }
    else {
        $this->isGutenberg = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if Gutenberg is active.

Not Call Class   if ( zwp_is_block_editor() ) {

```
Error 
       if ( zwp_is_block_editor() ) {
             class Auto_Save_Images_BLock_Editor
             {
                 ..............
             }
             new Auto_Save_Images_BLock_Editor();
       }

 OK
       if ( ! zwp_is_block_editor() ) {
             class Auto_Save_Images_Classic_Editor
             {
                 ..............
             }
             new Auto_Save_Images_Classic_Editor();
       }



if ( ! function_exists( 'zwp_is_block_editor' ) ) {

    function zwp_is_block_editor() {
        / 
        $screen = function_exists( 'get_current_screen' ) ? get_current_screen() : null;
        $is_block_editor = $screen ? $screen->is_block_editor() : false;

        if ( $is_block_editor ) {
            // Do your block editor stuff here
            return true;
        } else {
            // Do your classic editor stuff here
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```