# How to detect the usage of Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

The new editor called Gutenberg is here as plugin in 4.9, and as core functionality called Block Editor, in 5.0. Regarding to it, it is often needed to determine programmatically which editor is used to edit post or page in the site console. How to do it?

**Update:** There are number of outdated answers to similar question:

- [`gutenberg_post_has_blocks()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320653/how-to-detect-the-usage-of-gutenberg#comment473849_320653) - this function exists only in Gutenberg plugin, and not in 5.0 Core
- [`is_gutenberg_page()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/309955) - the same
- [`the_gutenberg_project()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320653/how-to-detect-the-usage-of-gutenberg#comment473850_320653) - the same
- [`has_blocks()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/312776) - does not work (returns false) when Classic Editor is on and its option "Default editor for all users" = "Block Editor"
- [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/319053) simply produces fatal error `Call to undefined function get_current_screen()`

So, before commenting this question and answer, please take a work to check what do you propose. Check it now, with 4.9 and current version of WordPress, and all possible combinations of Classic Editor and Gutenberg/Block Editor. I will be happy to discuss tested solution, not links to something.

Comment: add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_gutenberg_editor_test' );
function wpse_gutenberg_editor_test() {
    if( function_exists( 'is_gutenberg_page' ) && is_gutenberg_page() ) { 
        // your gutenberg editor related CODE here
    }   
    else {
        // this is not gutenberg.
        // this may not even be any editor, you need to check the screen.
    }   
}

Comment: please check this :https://artiss.blog/2018/09/detecting-per-post-use-of-gutenberg/

Comment: and this https://davidsword.ca/development/check-current-page-uses-gutenberg-classic-editor/

Comment: @vikrantzilpe please do not rely to an outdated information. It is better to test what you are writing. For example, `the_gutenberg_project()` function exists only in Gutenberg plugin, but not in the WP 5.0 Core.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if Gutenberg is currently in use](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309862/check-if-gutenberg-is-currently-in-use)

Comment: @T.Todua before making such comments, it is better to make a simple search across WP 5.0 core. There is such function at all in the Core.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Andrei's answer to that question is the correct answer.

Comment: @JacobPeattie if you only spent 10 minutes to check, you'd find that answer you pointed to does not work in some cases. Please read update to the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several variants:

- WordPress 4.9, Gutenberg plugin is not active
- WordPress 4.9, Gutenberg plugin is active
- WordPress 5.0, Block Editor by default
- WordPress 5.0, Classic Editor plugin is active
- WordPress 5.0, Classic Editor plugin is active, but in site console in “Settings > Writing” the option “Use the Block editor by default…” is selected

All the mentioned variants can be processed by the following code:

```
/**
 * Check if Block Editor is active.
 * Must only be used after plugins_loaded action is fired.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_active() {
    // Gutenberg plugin is installed and activated.
    $gutenberg = ! ( false === has_filter( 'replace_editor', 'gutenberg_init' ) );

    // Block editor since 5.0.
    $block_editor = version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.0-beta', '>' );

    if ( ! $gutenberg && ! $block_editor ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( is_classic_editor_plugin_active() ) {
        $editor_option       = get_option( 'classic-editor-replace' );
        $block_editor_active = array( 'no-replace', 'block' );

        return in_array( $editor_option, $block_editor_active, true );
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Check if Classic Editor plugin is active.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_classic_editor_plugin_active() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_plugin_active' ) ) {
        include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
    }

    if ( is_plugin_active( 'classic-editor/classic-editor.php' ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Function returns true if block editor is active by any means, and false – in the case if classic editor is here. This function must only be used after `plugins_loaded` action is fired.

P.S. Due release of version 1.2 of Classic Editor plugin, code is updated, as `classic-editor-replace` options now takes values not `replace` and `no-replace`, but `classic` and `block`.

Comment: not going o downvote, but it is not a fail safe answer. You should do detection based on actions or filters being triggered, not based n the existence of a file or a function. There are several ways to disable gutenberg and the classic editor is only one of them.

Comment: or to say it differently, you should never even try to detect if gutenberg is used or not, but instead just hook whatever functionality you need on the relevant gutenberg hooks in addition to hooking on the tinymce hooks

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'your_function_name' );
```

which is only fired when editing content with Gutenberg.

Comment: This code works only on editor page.

Comment: What about `enqueue_block_assets`?

Comment: `has_action( 'enqueue_block_assets' )` does the same what `has_filter( 'replace_editor'` in my code. It returns true if Classic Editor active and sets Classic Editor as default. It is better to check what you propose before writing.